# Operation hmset() takes forever

Tags: perl, redis

**UPD:** The code works just fine on a newer `Redis` module version: 1.904 vs 1.2001.

I'm trying to use `Redis` module from CPAN. It works OK when setting/getting scalar keys, however, I can't get hashes to work.

Here's my sample program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Redis;

my $red = Redis->new();
print "use\n";
$red->hmset(foo=>bar=>1, baz=>2);
print "set\n";
print "$_\n" for $red->hmget("foo", "bar", "baz");
```

And it hangs after printing "use".

Just using hmset/get from `redis-cli` works fine.

What's wrong with this code, and how should I deal with redis hashes from perl?

Comment: Voted to close: looks like newer versions of Redis work just fine.

Comment: Can you answer your own question in a way that would help others? If you do, you can select yours as the correct answer. It may seem strange, but it is the preferred way of dealing with situations like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was in an old enough version of the Redis module. On another server the code I've posted worked as expected.

The versions in question are 1.904 (works) and 1.2001 (does not).